# Scroll-chain containing to div without property in CSS on mobile

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile

I'm having an issue, primarily on mobile devices (in my case, an iOS device) where a div is seemingly preventing scroll-chaining; this is problematic because it's the first place you would touch to scroll (as opposed to a smaller div above it). Similarly for scrolling back up. I couldn't find anything online stating that there was a parameter or property default to mobile webkit that would contain a div. It seems though maybe this is behavior on iOS webkit, as notably, a second swipe on the final image **after the "bounce" of the scroll of the div returns to normal positioning** in the div allows a scroll (sometimes seemingly inconsistently?)

I've managed to recreate the issue with a test with minimum code repeated from my project (**view on mobile!** overscroll works fine on desktop)

https://codepen.io/hennigarj/pen/ZEjYrpW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <style>
        #container {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding-top: 4vh;
        }
            .flex-items {
                width: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .flex-items:nth-child(1) {
                display: block;
                height: 10vh;
            }
            .flex-items:nth-child(2) {
                display: block;
                margin-top: 4vh;
                margin-bottom: 4vh;
                height: 64vh;
                text-align: center;
            }
                .flex-items img {
                    max-width: 100%;
                }
            .flex-items:nth-child(3) {
                display: block;
                padding-bottom: 6vh;
            }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="flex-items">
            Div 1
        </div>
        <div class="flex-items">
            <section id="highlights">
                <div class="highlight">
                    <img src="https://placehold.jp/400x536.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="highlight">
                    <img src="https://placehold.jp/400x536.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="highlight">
                    <img src="https://placehold.jp/400x536.png" />
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-items">
            Div 3
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any ideas? I've tried all sorts of overflows and overscroll-behaviors on everything but nothing seems to fix this, and there is no value to specifically enable scroll-chaining through overscroll.

This is probably clear as day and I'm completely missing it.

Thank you :)

I've tried various different potential heights, overscroll-behaviors, overflows on divs (to no success). Ideally, hitting the end of the div would continue the scroll-chain past it, just as it does on desktop, but it contains. I've tried -webkit-overflow-scroling: auto as well.